# Get method caller fom set "function"

Tags: c#

It is pretty straightforward to get a method caller, or even get the property name change by using compiler services, like this:

```
public class EmployeeVM:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName=null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            // The compiler converts the above line to:
            // RaisePropertyChanged ("Name");
        }
    }

    private string _phone;

    public string Phone
    {
        get { return _phone; }
        set
        {
            _phone = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        // The compiler converts the above line to:
            // RaisePropertyChanged ("Phone");
        }
    }
}
```

But is it possible to get the caller of the "set" function from inside the set itself? I don't know how you'd syntactically define it in that scope. AKA, who is calling Phone= ?

Comment: C# 5 added Caller Information. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mvpawardprogram/archive/2012/03/26/introduction-of-new-features-in-c-5-0.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [StackFrame](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stackframe.aspx), in particular [GetMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stackframe.getmethod.aspx) that gives you method name (you'll need to pick one of previous stack frames, depending on if writing helper function to do so). Sample from the article:

```
            StackTrace st = new StackTrace();
            StackTrace st1 = new StackTrace(new StackFrame(true));
            Console.WriteLine(" Stack trace for Main: {0}",
               st1.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(st.ToString());
```

There are other similar questions that can be found by searching for StackFrame like [How do I find the type of the object instance of the caller of the current function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338740/how-do-i-find-the-type-of-the-object-instance-of-the-caller-of-the-current-funct)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately `[CallerMemberName]` AttributeUsage is set to `AttributeTargets.Parameter`, so it can only be used for parameters, like in method signatures

But you can use `StackFrame` like `Alexei Levenkov` mentioned

```
public string Phone
{
    get { return _phone; }
    set
    {
         string setterCallerName = new StackFrame(1).GetMethod().Name;

        _phone = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```